# Element not interactable with C# app that uses Chrome WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

**PREFACE**: After a lengthy Stack Overflow search I found two suggested solutions to solve the "element not interactable" problem I am having when I try to interact with the target node element.  Neither of them worked, as described below.

I have a C# app that uses the OpenQA.Selenium package to remote control a YouTube web page.  I am trying to click on a button on the page that opens a dialog box, but when I do I get the notorious "element not interactable" message.  I found the following two suggestions on Stack Overflow:

```js
Actions actions = new Actions(chromeDriver);
actions.MoveToElement(webElem);
actions.Perform();
```

And this suggestion that one commenter said is ill-advised because it can click on elements that are not visible or are below modal objects:

```js
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)chromeDriver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", webElem);
```

I tried the second one anyways to see if it worked.  Unfortunately, with the first suggestion that uses the `Actions` interface, I still got "element not interactable" message but this time on the `Perform()` statement.  The third attempt did *not* get the error message but it failed to click the button.  I know this because clicking the button opens a dialog window when it works, and no dialog window appeared when I tried the third solution.

Below is the code I am using to try and click on the element.  The collection it iterates are the elements I select via an XPath statement that finds the button I am want to click.  It tries every button that matches the XPath statement and skips those that fail to work.  Unfortunately, *none* of the 3 buttons found by the XPath statement work.

What is strange is that if I take the **exact** same XPath statement I am using in my C# app and plug it into the Chrome DevTools debugger, referencing the first element in the array of found elements, *it works*:

```
$x(strXPath)[0].click()
```

But so far nothing I have tried from C# app works.  Does anyone have an idea on why I am having this problem?

```cs
        public IWebElement ClickFirstInteractable(ChromeDriver chromeDriver)
        {
            string errPrefix = "(ClickFirstInteractable) ";

            if (this.DOM_WebElemensFound == null || this.DOM_WebElemensFound.Count() < 1)
                throw new NullReferenceException(errPrefix + "The DOM_WebElementsFound collection is empty.");

            IWebElement webElemClicked = null;

            foreach (IWebElement webElem in this.DOM_WebElemensFound)
            {
                // Try and "click" it.
                try
                {
                    // First make sure the element is visible, or we will get
                    //  the "element not interactable" error.

                    /* FIRST ATTEMPT, didn't work. 
                     * 
                    webElem.scrollIntoView(true);
                    webElem.Click(); // <<<<<----- Error occurs here
                     */

                    /* SECOND ATTEMPT using Actions, didn't work
                     *  and I go the error message when the Perform() statement executes.
                    Actions actions = new Actions(chromeDriver);
                    actions.MoveToElement(webElem);
                    actions.Perform(); // <<<<<----- Error occurs here
                     */

                    /* THIRD ATTEMPT using script execution, didn't work.
                     * I did not get the error message, but the button did not get clicked.
                     */

                    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)chromeDriver;
                    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElem);
                    executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", webElem);

                    // Click operation accepted.  Stop iteration.
                    webElemClicked = webElem;
                    break;
                }
                catch (ElementNotInteractableException exc)
                {
                    // Swallow this exception and go on to the next element found by the XPath expression.
                    System.Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }
            }

            return webElemClicked;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post URL?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario by clicking on a "hidden" button, waiting for the modal to appear, then acting on that modal, etc.

I hope it helps you!

```
const string Target = @"https://www.youtube.com/";

using var driver = new ChromeDriver();
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
{
    PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250),
};

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Target);

// i don't consent cookies to 
// save time, so just do it 
// here manually and then press enter to console 
Console.ReadLine();

var menuLocator = By.XPath("//a[@id = 'video-title-link'][1]" +
                            "/ancestor::div[@id = 'meta']" +
                            "/following-sibling::div[@id = 'menu']" +
                            "//button[@class = 'style-scope yt-icon-button']");

var menu = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(menuLocator));
var actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.MoveToElement(menu).Click().Perform();

var shareLocator = By.XPath("//div[@id = 'contentWrapper']//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'Share']");
var share = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(shareLocator));
actions.MoveToElement(share).Click().Perform();

var copyLinkLocator = By.XPath("//button[@aria-label = 'Copy']");
var copyLink = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(copyLinkLocator));
actions.MoveToElement(copyLink).Click().Perform();
```